# how to know if ElementReference is present in dom

Tags: blazor

Is it possible to tell on `onAfterRenderAsync` if a certain `ElementReference` is present in the DOM (rendered) ?
I have something like this:

```
@if (condition) {
<input @ref="elem1" />
}
```

and on `onAfterRenderAsync` I need to know if `elem1` is rendered, is this possible ( aside from looking at `condition` ) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check it like this

```
if (elem1.Context is not null)
   { 
       //  do something
   }
else
   {
       //  do something
   }
```

Comment: works only the first time and after it got rendered, seems like 2nd time, and after even if the element is not present the context will not be null

Comment: There is Id property as well in ElementReference , you can try it and see if it works for your case, else there is always a JavaScript option to consider